# How to understand the domain of an operator?

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

This is the book of functional analysis by Rudin.
I have a little bit confused to understand the Definition of 13.1 and its explaination in the below.
My understanding is following:
if we divide operator into two situation(bounded, unbounded). According to line 4 to line 8, if the operator is bounded, then we can find an extension such that its domain is the whole space $H$.  if we talk about the domain of an bounded operator is no sense? Is there some misunderstanding? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your problem is. The text just tells you that if $T$ is bounded on $\mathscr{D}(H)$, then you can extend it to a bounded operator on $H$ in the usual sense.

Comment: I mean if T is bounded, then it is always possible to find an extension of T such that and the domain of this extension is the whole space. Then it is not necessary to talk about the domain of T.

Comment: Can we extend this definition to any Banach space?

Comment: Yes, this concept becomes only useful when you work with unbounded operators  (see the name of the chapter). I believe this is what Rudin means to say with his remark. And yes, the concept also makes sense for any Banach space, but his follow-up remark may not apply anymore since you can't find orthonormal complements anymore.

Comment: Your meaning is that if T is bounded operator on Banach space. We can't find the extension of T such that the domain of this extension is the whole space?

Comment: Do you know how to find the domain of an operator in different space? e.g. $\Delta$ in $C_\infty$/$L^p$?

Comment: You can't find a bounded extension in general.

Comment: I have no idea to find the domain of an operator in a Banach space. It would be nice if you can share some idea with me.

Comment: I have the following problems. 
1). If we know an operator $T:X\to X$, where $X$ is a Banach space. How should I find the domain of this operator? 2) If we only know an operator, how should I find the suitable Banach space and suitable domain? these problems confued me a lot! e.g. $\Delta$.

Comment: The domain of an operator is not something you can find, it is given by definition, both in the classical bounded and unbounded setting.